# Highcharts - Local export server installation issue (Tomcat Java)

Tags: tomcat, highcharts, export

I have tried to follow the tutorial on Highcharts website here : http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server but didn't success.I got the "highcharts-export-web.war" file and it was deployed on my tomcat server. I can access the demo page by typing "localhost:8080/highcharts-export-web" and when I click on "Generate image" I obtain the following message
" 
Oops..,

${message}
"

I have checked Tomcat's logs and i can read "Error, PhantomJS could not start" and "POOL EXHAUSTED!!"

Got any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that the phantomJS executable was not started. What OS are you running this on? If it is Windows I have found that the read only properties on the folder containing phantomjs can affect whether or not it can be started. Did you verify that the paths you set up in app-convert.properties are correct?

Comment: I'm running this on Windows indeed. Just got a new message when trying to gererate a chart using the demo page :
"
Oops..,

Sorry, the server is handling too many requests at the moment. Please try again.
"
I modified all the permissions. Still not working.


My "app-convert-properties" is the following :

# the host and port phantomjs listens to
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 7777

exec = /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/phantomjs.exe

script = /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js

Comment: Your exec variable points to phantomjs.exe..?? Did you install a windows executable on a Linux server, perhaps

Comment: You say you are on Windows but the paths you list are *nix format but with a windows executable like @gertvaartjes says.

Comment: It appears that I probably am on a Linux server in fact.
Just downloaded a Linux version of Phantomjs, I have that now (in my app-convert.properties file) :

host = 127.0.0.1

port = 7777

# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs

exec = /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs

# name of the convert script used by phantomjs

script = /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js

Same problem.

Comment: Can you see if the phantomJS process is running on your server?

Comment: When having problems while using the export-server, the first thing you could do is to enable logging Debug messages. This can give you a clue of what's going wrong. To enable Debug messages, uncomment these lines in highcharts-export/highcharts-export-web/src/main/resources/log4j.properties

# Debug specific class
log4j.logger.services=DEBUG
log4j.logger.converter=DEBUG
log4j.logger.exporter=DEBUG
log4j.logger.pool=DEBUG

Comment: wergled > When I check my logs, it appears that PhantomJS is not running :
"java.lang.RuntimeException : Error, PhantomJS couldnot start"

@gert vaartjes
Done it already and got this :
[DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-1 01:10:50] (AbstractPool.java:poolCleaner:53) HC: queue size: 0 poolSize 0

[DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-1 01:10:50] (AbstractPool.java:poolCleaner:74) in cleanpool, the surplus or shortage is: -1
[DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-1 01:10:50]

Comment: (ServerObjectFactory.java:create:46) in makeObject, /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/phantomjs.exe, highcharts-convert.js, 127.0.0.1

[DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-1 01:10:50] (ServerObjectFactory.java:getAvailablePort:103) Nothing free in Portusage {}

[DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-1 01:10:50] (Server.java:<init>:54) [/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/phantomjs.exe, /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/temp/export5078961406786962755/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js, -host, 127.0.0.1, -port, 7777]

[ERROR] [pool-1-thread-1 01:10:50]  Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

Comment: Even though I've changed app-convert.properties to this and did a new mvn clean install in order to have a new .war :
exec = /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
script = /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js

Comment: Solved ! Was using a 32 bits version of PhantomJS while my server was a 64 bits one.
However I have a new error message now :
"Something went wrong while converting. Error converting SVGConnection refused"

Checked my logs and found this (my poolSize is 4):

http://pastebin.com/it43Mh2M

Comment: Okay, I'm now using the same port in"app-convert.properties"file as the server's port.Is that correct? Because this way, the application (demo page highcharts-export-web) returns at least an image file when clicking on "Highcharts config object(JSON)"(even though it is unreadable).I have tried to ask for others file formats (svg) by clicking on Highcharts config object (JSON) one more time and I obtain the following with Notepad++: http://pastebin.com/ANkGWGiH  That has nothing to do with phantomjs or highcharts, right? For information Saiku was already installed on the server I am working on.

Comment: I would not set up the phantomJS port to be the same as the Tomcat's webserver port.

Comment: Solved ! I had to use ip address directly as host. Well, I want to use it as a button in a chart on my server. How can I do that ? Because I was using the demo page at myserver.com:8080/highcharts-export-web from the start. (The automatically loaded page)

Comment: To get it so your HC on your page can be exported you need to add the URL to the export server (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.url). For yours it would be <your export server IP or website address>/higcharts-export-web/. The ending slash is important.